# open wifi Captive portal w/only local net (no internet/wan)?

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, iptables, dnsmasq, captiveportal

I am trying to set up a wireless 'test' box to use on a private club (11,000 acres). The initial tests won't need anything fancy, it will just be checking the visibility of a hotspot from a high-point in the middle of the property. But if it proves to have good visibility, later tests will be (hopefully) promoted by the club and made aware to members. I would like to set up a captive portal to redirect them to a comments page where they can post a quick message if they were able to connect and hopefully say what they think about the idea.

This is going to be going on a raspberry pi running debian wheezy. So the less overhead the better.

Most of the examples I see online of captive portal are based on having an internet connection and/or a NAT scheme set up. I just need a hotspot and a single web-page for these promotional tests. If possible, I would like to trigger any devices capable to suggest or otherwise open a browser to go to the promotional landing page. It would also be nice if some kind of dns masquerading or other mechanism was in place to redirect all browser traffic in the event their device doesn't support a pop-up.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT 2022/06/05:  With further testing and packet sniffing, it turned out that the android versions in question hard code the ip of the google server used for the 'online check' (8.8.8.8).  When on an arbitrary IP, it's not looking for requests to 8.8.8.8 and thus it doesn't grab the online-check and won't redirect. If you set the AP to use this address (when not internet connected), the pop-up will usually trigger.
However, this solution is not ideal. Hacking the IP stack to specifically grab that request to 8.8.8.8 is outside my wheelhouse of knowledge. If anyone knows how to do this or has another potential solution, I would be interested in hearing it.

Comment: any luck? kindly update if you found a solution

Comment: actually no. I have the wifi working and I can redirect all traffic on the browser to the page, but despite checking multiple sources I still have not had any luck triggering the pop-up.

Comment: (the dns redirection is the same simple parameter used on live internet portals in dhcpmasq btw - just redirecting anything on port 80 or 443 to a given url)

Comment: Any luck after 6 years? I'm still looking for the same

Comment: yes and no. It turns out those versions of android hard code the IP of the 'online check'. If you set the AP to the google address (8.8.8.8) when it's not internet connected, the pop-up 'usually' works.

Comment: I say 'almost' because I would prefer to use an arbitrary ip but that would require getting down into the ip stack to specifically grab that request to 8.8.8.8 and that's beyond my knowledge.